# Installing SSL certificate for Application hosted on Virtualised Windows IIS

Tags: iis, ssl, apache-2.4

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 that has WebMin installed and running Apache. I am also running Virt Manager to have a virtualised Windows Server.

I am wanting to setup an SSL certificate for an application that is running within IIS on the virtualised Windows Server.

I'm not sure where exactly I should be installing an SSL certificate, on the Linux Server or within IIS. Can someone please help point me in the right direction as to where I should be setting up the configuration for this?

Comment: Which web server will be serving requests?

Comment: So the requests will come through to the Ubuntu head and apache will do a pass through to the Windows IIS application on a specific port for the application

Comment: Since, IIS will be serving the web requests, SSL certificate should be installed in IIS web server.

Comment: Ok, for testing purposes I set up a self signed certificate on the Windows server. I've set up a port that will go through as HTTPS to the Windows Server too and it will display under HTTPS under localhost correctly. How would I get apache to pass through the request still using HTTPS? Currently I'm using a Virtual Host however it doesn't work at the moment and just reports CONNECTION_CLOSED

Comment: Posted code as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to this. The SSL certificate is installed on the Apache server. I personally stored the cert and key file within the /etc/apache2/ folder within a folder I made called /ssl/. The way I did this was using the following VirtualHost setup:

```
<VirtualHost your-website.com:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.key
    ProxyPass / http://your-internal-ip-address-for-windows/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://your-internal-ip-address-for-windows/
    ServerName your-website.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I created a re-direct VirtualHost so that it would always route through to HTTPS:

```
<VirtualHost your-website.com:80>
    Redirect permanent / https://your-website.com
    ServerName your-website.com
</VirtualHost>
```